# How to make transmission code about CAN protocol

Tags: c, stm32, keil, can-bus, nucleo

I'm using NUCLEO-F103RB Board and SN65HVD230 CAN transceiver.
and CAN mode is CAN_MODE_LOOPBACK.
workspace is keil uvision(IDE), STM32 ST-LINK(debugger?).

I have a sample code what my teacher gives me.
it's STMICRO'S sample code.
but i really don't know how to use..

first, I know how to set stdId, DLC, DATA[0]~[7]
it is like this.

```
tx_msg.StdId = 0x701;
tx_msg.DLC = 8;
tx_msg.Data[0] = 0x11;
tx_msg.Data[1] = 0x22;
tx_msg.Data[2] = 0x33;
tx_msg.Data[3] = 0x44;
tx_msg.Data[4] = 0x55;
tx_msg.Data[5] = 0x66;
tx_msg.Data[6] = 0x77;
tx_msg.Data[7] = 0x88;
```

as I know, next step is making transmission code.
but how to make trasmission code?

1. using `can_tx(argument...)` like this?
2. setting register about CAN protocol (but my teacher said there is no changing register or interrupt.)

also, I think this is transmit function, maybe....

```
can_tx(uint32_t CanTxMsgTypeDef *tx_msg),uint32_t timeout)
```

internal argument->()

Comment: First you had to read some basic stuff about CAN and your CAN Controller!

Comment: Are you asking how to find the function documentation or how to call a function in C?

Comment: @Lundin i'm wondering how to call a function in C. please!!!!